# issue in installing node+npm using nvm in Ubuntu 16.04 32bit

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

i choose nvm to manage my node and npm version in Ubuntu.everying thing goes well until i run `npm`, it gives this:

```
root@allenWang:~/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin# npm
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm: line 2: `;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode'
```

i think it may be caused by intall error. so i remove all node and npm files and alians beside the nvm. reinstall,error comes the same.

i open the  `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm` to find the error.it goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode
// windows: running "npm blah" in this folder will invoke WSH, not node.
/*global WScript*/
```

it's strange about the `；`，any body meet the same question,and have any idea?

Comment: (nvm maintainer here)

You should not need to be `cd`d into any of nvm's directories. `cd && which node && nvm current`, what's that output?

Comment: thank for your help. i get the result like this :                           `root@allenWang:~# cd && which node && nvm current`
`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/node
v9.4.0`

Comment: Great! What about `which npm && npm --version`?

Comment: i get this : 
`root@allenWang:~# which npm && npm --version`

`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm`

`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/npm: line 2: ;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode'`

Comment: That's baffling; what happens if you uninstall and reinstall it? (`nvm deactivate && nvm uninstall 9.4.0 && nvm install 9.4.0`)

Comment: it's puzzled. thank for your help.i think it may be caused by env in ubuntu. i reinstall the system.Everything goes well. thank you again